# Are foot sweeps legal in kendo competition?

Tags: throwing, sport, kendo

I had recently seen two examples of a foot sweep (*de ashi barai*) used in a kendo match to fell an opponent before striking them:

| [image: Maeda senshu does ashi-barai to Tanaka senshu at the final of 2018 All Japan Police Team Championship Final (Osaka vs. Kanagawa)] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| <sub>2018 All Japan Police Team Championship Final</sub> | <sub>2014 National Police Kendo Tournament (First Division)</sub> |

Is this a legal move? If so, what other types of throw are legal?

Answer (score 3):

I have not found an authoritative set of rules for Kendo (odd, to me, but maybe I'm using the wrong search terms) other than [this brief set](https://kendo.supplies/kendo-rules/) that mention no tripping or shoving opponents out of bounds, but the footage your provide is from a "Police Kendo" match, where they apparently specifically allow a broader variety of techniques. This [discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/martialarts/comments/5o4cw5/footage_of_a_kendo_match_before_foot_sweeps_were/dch40b7?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) claims that body checks and striking a downed opponent are legal in regular Kendo, and that the Police and Imperial Guard (I think they call it [tokuren](https://kenshi247.net/blog/2018/06/15/kendotokuren/#:%7E:text=Acceptance%20into%20the%20kendo%20and,other%20aspects%20of%20police%20work.)) run their own competitions with foot sweeps being legal.

Comment: This answer is correct to the best of my limited knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

*Just to add some sources:*

I can't find a freely accessible copy of the FIK's *Regulations Of Kendo Shiai and Shinpan*, but it appears most local rulesets based off of this<sup>[1](http://www.oxfordkendo.com/DOCS/Kendo_Regulations.pdf) [2](http://www.kendoaustralia.asn.au/publicdocs/referee_booklet_2011_edition3.pdf)  [3](http://www.kendo.lv/documents/regulations_of_kendo_shiai_and_shinpan.pdf)</sup> prohibit foot sweeps (though body checks appear to be permitted under some rules if performed to instigate a technique):

> **(Miscellaneous and Prohibitive acts)**
> ...
> 2. Tripping up or sweeping the opponent’s legs from under them
> 3. Unfairly shoving or pushing an opponent outside the court with no attempt to preform a technique;